Qt 5.15.2 item disappear when used in StackView
I have this QML files
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component {
        id: firstPage

        BasePage {
            color: "red"
            bottomBar.rightButton.text: qsTr("Next")
            bottomBar.rightButton.visible: true
            onBottomBarRightButtonClicked: stackView.push(secondPage)
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: secondPage

        BasePage {
            color: "blue"
            onBackKeyPressed: stackView.pop()
        }
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: firstPage
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}

//BasePage.qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Page {
    default property alias content: contentItem.data
    property alias bottomBar: bottomBar
    property alias color: background.color
    signal bottomBarLeftButtonClicked()
    signal bottomBarCentralButtonClicked()
    signal bottomBarRightButtonClicked()
    signal backKeyPressed()

    id: basePageItem
    focusPolicy: Qt.ClickFocus

    Keys.onReleased: {
        if(event.key !== Qt.Key_Back && event.key !== Qt.Key_Escape)
            return;

        backKeyPressed()
        event.accepted = true
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout {
            id: basePage
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 0

            Item {
                id: contentItem
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }

            BottomBar {
                id: bottomBar
                Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height * 0.1
                Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
                onLeftButtonClicked: bottomBarLeftButtonClicked()
                onCentralButtonClicked: bottomBarCentralButtonClicked()
                onRightButtonClicked: bottomBarRightButtonClicked()
            }
        }
    }
}

//BottomBar.qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Rectangle {
    property alias leftButton: leftButton
    property alias centralButton: centralButton
    property alias rightButton: rightButton
    signal leftButtonClicked()
    signal centralButtonClicked()
    signal rightButtonClicked()

    id: bottomBar
    color: "#fafafa"
    visible: leftButton.visible || centralButton.visible || rightButton.visible

    Row {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: width * 0.02

        Item {
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width * 0.32

            Button {
                id: leftButton
                anchors.fill: parent
                visible: false
                onClicked: bottomBar.leftButtonClicked()
            }
        }

        Item {
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width * 0.32

            Button {
                id: centralButton
                anchors.fill: parent
                visible: false
                onClicked: bottomBar.centralButtonClicked()
            }
        }

        Item {
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width * 0.32

            Button {
                id: rightButton
                anchors.fill: parent
                visible: false
                onClicked: bottomBar.rightButtonClicked()
            }
        }
    }
}

When the program starts everything works well and the bottomBar of the first page is visible.
Then I click on the NEXT button -> second page is shown.
Then I go back to the first page and the bottom bar of the first page has disappeared.
Am I doing something wrong?
Note: everything works well if I use a Loader, the problem seems related to StackView in some way
